# Get Dice Coefficient between 2 c# sets using Lambda expression

Tags: c#-4.0, lambda, set, c#-3.0

I have a class which offers a public method that is Dice set operation between the current set and the passed set as argument. I read many articles about Lambda and was wondering how to do that like the following ?

```
public float FindDice(Set<T> other) => 
    (((float) (2 * this.Intersect<T>(other).Count<T>())) / ((float) (this._count + other.Count)))
```

However this is not working in c# can anyone please explain to me why with some theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is different from C++, as a working example, you can do something like this

```
Func<HashSet<int>, HashSet<int>, float> findDice = (HashSet<int> a, HashSet<int> b) => { return (float)(a.Intersect<int>(b).Count<int>() / (float)(a.Count + b.Count));  };
```

Now `findDice` is a named lambda function.

Comment: I don't want to pass both sets, since the first set is already passed to the class I would need to use "this" as set "a" here is my major problem

Comment: if you need a method of a class, I don't see the point to use a lambda expression.

Comment: Actually, this is a part of API and the structure of it requires such class representation, if it was me, I would just use get-return